# How do I find out if Sql server Agent's login has rights to a DB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent

How do I find out if the SQL server Agent's login has rights to the target DB, that is the DB on which I will be executing a query ?

Also, how do I find the service that's controlling Agent on the job server and find out the login it's using ?

Is there a query for these things ?

Thanks.

Comment: Downvoters please tell me why the -2 ?

Comment: Didn't downvote but I think it's because this is a question that you can easily find on google.

Answer (score 1):

**Account**

There is no documented way to find out what the current service account for the agent is, at least not before SQL Server 2008R2.

As Jon commented below, in SQL Server 2008R2 SP1 and later you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_services;
```

For versions prior to that you can try one of the following:

Aaron suggested a xp_regread solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324407/get-service-account-details-of-the-sql-agent-service
But I currently can't get it to work, and even if you get it to work, there is no guarantee that it still works after the next SQL Server patch was installed.

The easiest would be to start the SQL Server Configuration Manager on the instance's server and look it up in there.

Alternatively you could use the [SUSER_SNAME()](http://sqlity.net/en/1795/mystery-suser_name-suser_sname-functions/) function to do something like

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME() AS LoginName
  INTO tempdb.dbo.AgentAccountTable;
```

Put this statement into a job, execute that job and then look up the value in that table:

```
SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.AgentAccountTable;
```

---

**Permissions**

As for the permissions: The Agent Server Account must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx). Therefore it will have access to any database.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204542.aspx (introduced in 2008 R2 SP1 IIRC).

Comment: Of course if you don't need to find out the agent service account programmatically (which would be cumbersome to do using a job anyway, meaning only that you still have to manually create the job, run it, and check the table), you can just check the SQL Server Configuration Manager or Control Panel > Services applet.